# UIStackView create a table with a gap in IB

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I want to create a table, using UIStackViews in IB.

My previous approach to get the following:

[image]

Has been to add a label with "nothing" in it to force the gap between scores and score this turn.

[image]

Now surely there is a better way than adding this blank label?

I've already tried the solution above, and have also tried to set the spacing but this really does not make sense as the text will be dynamic at runtime. This isn't homework, I've looked elsewhere on SO and have a working solution but it does not seem to be a very good solution (adding a blank label is obviously poor). The details above represent a minimum example of the problem and my inadequate solution. This isn't homework, and there are images to illustrate the problem and current solution above.

**The question**
I want to create the table above, but with a solution that is production ready and maintainable, using IB (not code) and a UIStackView (no libraries) for my own understanding of the use of UIStackView.

Comment: Hi, you need above Table using UISackView???

Comment: I created the above table using UIStackview, and this required putting a spacer empty label in the UIStackview. Sacked indeed, Mr. Alcatraz.

Comment: No its really Bad Approach to putting a Label in UIStackView

Comment: You can use Constraint...

Comment: YOu want to keep SCORE THIS TURN, 5(Player 1) & 0(Player 2) in the same Horizontal position??

Comment: @WishIHadThreeGuns You need to go with custom reusable cell in tableView instead of use UIStackview.

Comment: A table view for a 3 * 3 table? The amount of code to do that is rather large... you'd use a collectionview, but even then it's verging on insane as the complexity to do a small component like this ... I thought I'd specified using a UIStackView?

Comment: It would make more sense to me to put each players data into a single stack view. (When I say more sense, this is relative, this should be done using a collection view imo). Then put the headings into a stackview and set alignment right on it. Or something?

Comment: Tbh... I’d probably just go for using constraints without a stack view possibly. It’s not a complex view at all. Just add the constraints for each row and column etc... if you’re not adding anything to it then that should be fairly easy.